# Setup SVN/LAMP/Test Server/ on linux, where to start?

Tags: php, linux, svn

I have a ubuntu machine I have setup. I installed apache2 and php5 on it. I can access the web server from other machines on the network via http://linux-server. I have subversion installed on it. I also have vsftpd installed on it so I can ftp to it from another computer on the network.

Myself and other users currently use dreamweaver to checkin-checkout files directly from our live site to make changes.

I want the connect to the linux server from pc. make the changes on the test server until ready and then pushed to the live site. I want to use subversion also into this workflow as well. but not sure what the best workflow is or how to set this up.

I have no experience with linux, svn, or even using a test server, the checkin/out we are currently doing is the way I have always done it.

I have hit many snags already just getting what I have setup because of my lack of knowledge in the area. Dreamweaver 5 has integration with subversion but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

I want to setup and create the best workflow possible.

I dont expect anyone to be able to give me an answer that will enlighten me enough to know everthing I need to know to do what I want to do (altough if possible that would be great) instead I am looking for maybe a knowledge path like answer. Like a general outline of what I need to do accompanied with links to learn how to do it. like read this book to learn linux, then read this article to learn svn, etc., then you should know what to do. I would be happy just getting it all setup, but I would like to know what I am actually doing while setting it up too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've solved your issue by now, but for future reference to other users, here's the steps I would suggest to get started:

1. [Create a repository for your project](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) (in Ubuntu)
2. [Host the SVN repo using Apache](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51753)
3. I'd read up on the [subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) to look at some strategies for development with SVN.

To connect to your SVN machine, you'll need to use it's IP or hostname instead of your svn live site you mentioned.  With proper forwarding, it's easy to access it from anywhere.